# Validate method for a specific action mapping

Tags: validation, struts2

I have 2 action mapping in my struts 2 xml file that map to 2 methods of the same action class as below

```
<action name="action1" class="com.web.action.MyAction method="myMethod1">
            <result>success1.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="action2" class="com.web.action.MyAction method="myMethod2">
            <result>success2.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I have also overridden the validate() method of the ActionSupport class. Now I want that this validate method should execute only for action1 and NOT fro action2. Is there is way to do so? I know i can put the 2 methods in seperate action classes and this will work.

Answer (score 1):

The "validation" interceptor uses the same prefixed method utility as the "prepare" interceptor.

The "validation" interceptor will call method-specific validation methods; for your specific example:

```
public void validateMyMethod1() { ... }
public void validateMyMethod2() { ... }
```

See the ["validation" interceptor docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation-interceptor.html), but for better/more detail, the ["prepare" interceptor docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/prepare-interceptor.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well as of now this is not possible in a straight way to tell at which action calling we should call the validate method, there are few solution possible

1. Move them to separate classes as suggested by you.
2. Switch to programmatic validation approach like create a method same `myCustomvalidation` and you can call that method from inside `myMethod1` method.

Comment: yes, swithing to custom validation means you have all way to control the flow and other aspects

Comment: I like your second solution. Can i do something like this in 
myCustomValidation:
public String myMethod1() {
if(!myCustomValidation) {
return INPUT;
}
//perform the action task
return SUCCESS;
}

public boolean myCustomValidation() {
//if not valid 
addFieldError("myField","field not valid");
return false;
//else return true;
}

Comment: ok, just to confirm, if i add a field error and return INPUT from my customValidate() method, this will work in the same way as if i add field error from validate() method? I mean validation error will be shown corresponding to the field?

Comment: yes, since fieldError will be available on the valuestack and moreover you can try as see how its going