# How to use different validate methods in one action class in Struts 2

Tags: java, validation, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I have an action class and it has two action methods in it. I want separate validate methods for it. I am new to Struts2. I want something like this. I think it can be implemented by validation interceptor but how?

```
public class ApplicantRegistration extends ActionSupport{

 public String method1(){
   // validate1
 }

 public String method2(){
   // validate2
 }

 @override
 public void validate1(){
  // validations
 }

 public void validate2(){
 //validations
 }

}
```

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12318328/438992) etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To separate validation on methods use `validate` prefix

```
public class ApplicantRegistration extends ActionSupport{

 public String method1(){
   // action1
 }

 public String method2(){
   // action2
 }

 public void validateMethod1(){
  // validate method1
 }

 public void validateMethod2(){
  // validate method2
 }

}
```